# OR Operator in SOQL with Castiron

Tags: salesforce, soql, cast-iron

I'm facing an issue while creating a SOQL from within Castiron Studio 7.0.0.2

```
SELECT Id FROM Account
WHERE
Field_Feed__c = 'particular flag value'
**OR**
RecordTypeId = '012400000009ae1'
```

The OR operator just doesn't work. And when I say it doesn't work I mean I can't even validate the query, because I get a syntax error
[image: Syntax Error]

But, but, but if I put

```
SELECT Id FROM Account
WHERE
Field_Feed__c = 'particular flag value'
**AND**
RecordTypeId = '012400000009ae1'
```

it works fine. Why it doesn't with **OR**? 
What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Studio version 7.0x has lots of internal bugs and most unstable version.
I am using cast iron studio version 7.5.1.0, the most stable version of IBM CastIron/AppConnect till now. This version doesn't have any SOQL related issues which you mentioned in this post. Attaching my studio screenshot, which validates the query without any error.

Download link: [Studio Download Link 7.5.1.0](https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm~WebSphere&product=ibm/WebSphere/WebSphere%20Cast%20Iron%20Cloud%20integration&release=7.5.1.0&platform=All&function=fixId&fixids=7.5.1.0-WS-WCI-20160324-1342_H11_64.32bit.studio,7.5.1.0-WS-WCI-20160324-1342_H11_64.studio&includeSupersedes=0)

[SOQL Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbToa.png)

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure this out, in all honesty this issues doesn't make any sense at all. So what I did was to add a Filter and Profile activity, and in there I placed all my logic ORs. Crappy Castiron.